Clarification about caching fault rate proof: How is it established that a partition of phases into blocks exists?
I am reading "On paging with locality of reference" and I am trying to understand Theorem 1.
For some prerequisites, their idea is to consider only paging sequences that satisfy "locality of reference". That is, there is a concave function $f$ (Definition 1) such such that the paging sequence is "consistent with" $f$. Then, under this restriction certain bounds can be made about the fault rate of a particular algorithm $\mathcal{A}$. The fault rate of an algorithm over any possible paging sequence that is "consistent with $f$" is denoted $F_{\mathcal{A}}(f)$.
To be "consistent with $f$" means that "maximum number of distinct pages referenced in a window of size $n$ is at most $f(n)$". Also, they define a function $f^{-1}$ for a corresponding $f$ which "is the smallest possible size of a window containing $m$ distinct pages."
Now back to Theorem 1, it is claimed that:

Theorem 1 Let $\mathcal{A}$ be any deterministic algorithm, then
$$F_{\mathcal{A}}(f) \geq \frac{k-1}{f^{-1}(k+1)-2}$$

From what I understand is the proof works in two parts: First construct a "bad" paging sequence $\sigma_n$. Then show $\sigma_n$ is consistent with $f$. I am still stuck on the first part of the proof.
To incur a page fault they consider only one more page than cache can contain entirely. They define a block as "a subsequence of requests, all to the page
that was not in $\mathcal{A}$'s fast memory at the end of the previous block." I do agree with the paper that accessing a page not in fast memory incurs a penalty of $1$, but why is a block a subsequence instead of a single page request?
Furthermore, they define a phase as a $f^{-1}(k+1) - 2$ length subsequence of a request consisting of $k-1$ blocks. They say:

In each phase, block $j, 1 \leq j \leq k − 1$, starts with request $f^{−1}(j + 1) − 1$. Note that the partitioning of the phases into blocks is well-defined, since $f(2) = 2$.

It is unclear to me how each phase is guaranteed to be partition into $k-1$ subdivisions "since $f(2) = 2$". Any clarification as to why this is true would be greatly appreciated.
